# Vision API Android detect grid on image

Tags: android

I'm not sure where to start with this one, I have an image with a repeatable grid pattern and I am trying to detect and create a digital representation of that grid over the camera view. [image: Grid]

If I have my rear camera preview hovering over this image, I would like it to detect gridlines and then overlay a digital redline of the grids. Similar to the face/barcode detection but a grid detector.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should be your starting direction. see the sudoku grid detection http://aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-opencv-detection/ and Extracting the grid http://aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-opencv-extracting-grid/

Note: This is using the OpenCV Image processing library.